# What is new in pgf 2.10

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-2.10

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/ shows that 2 days ago (25 Oct 2010) version 2.10 of PGF (Tikz) is released.

What are new functionalities in this version? (not bugfixes, but features)

Comment: We could use some of the frequent posters to pgf-users on this site.  I tried to invite them but I have already unsubscribed so I have to get back on the list.  If you're a subscriber let them know about us here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.texample.net/tikz/builds/ provides a nice overview of what's been happening. Some bugfixes are mentioned, but it's mostly about features. Of course, this is the unstable development branch, not what the actual release consists of, but it could give some pointers to new features.